# How to use RabbitTemplate sendAndReceive function with custom message?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm new at Spring AMQP. I wanna use sendAndReceive() with using custom message.

```
public void send (String exchange, String routingKey, MyCustomMessage message){
    CorrelationData correlationData = new CorrelationData("correlation-data");
    rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(exchange, routingKey, message, correlationData);
}
```

But this code occur error message

> Make 'MyCustomMessage'extends org.springframework.amqp.core.Message'

Extending Message is the only way to use CustomMessage?
I didn't extend when I using convertAndSend function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; as long as it is compatible with the `MessageConverter` in the template (default `SimpleMessageConverter` can handle `Serializable` or you can use a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` for JSON-friendly classes, or you can use a custom message converter).

Then, use `template.convertSendAndReceive(...)` instead of `sendAndReceive`.